# How should I limit active ssh connections

Tags: ssh

I have added this `myuser   hard   maxlogins   1` to `/etc/security/limits.conf` and it works ok if I run `ssh myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` in command line. but if I run `ssh -p 22 -N -D 5060 myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, I can run unlimited concurrent connections. Is there anyway to limit this type of ssh?

Comment: `MaxStartups` setting in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file may help.

Comment: in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config is UsePAM enabled?